# Is there a comparison list between VisualForce Tags and it equivalent HTML tags?

Tags: html, salesforce, visualforce

Like `Apex:OutputPanel` is similar to Div/Span, do we have any such list of comparison. Does such a comparison exist?

Comment: Although your question looks okay to me 1) too short questions tend to be voted down, and 2) questions considered askings for software recommendations are also closed as offtopic. In the first case, give more details even if they don't seem important for you. In the second case, give a try to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Hey Peter, not asking for any software recommendation, but I am trying to figure out if we have anything similar to SFDC cheetsheets which would describe the similarities/comparison of Visualforce tag with their equivalent HTML tags.

Comment: Well, some find the rules of the other voters maybe too rigorous. Finally a vote decides about your question. In most cases, it is very important to give many details. Now somebody thinks your question is "too broad", so make it more specific. I suspect the real problem is that asking for a comparison table is not really a 100% programming question (this may be the reason why you didn't get an answer until now), although I think it is yet acceptable.